# checkbox value in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i'm using Mvc checkbox.

by default the rendering a checkbox like below.

```
<input id="tets" type="checkbox" value="true" name="test"/>
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="test"/>
```

so whn itry to access

```
$("#tets").val() returns true, but defaultly it is false.
```

Any idea how to access checkbox using jquery

Comment: Is the "#tets" typo also in your actual code? $("#test").val() should be all you need to access the checkbox value.

Answer (score 23):

```
var value = $("#tets").is(":checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to do it like this:

```
var value = $('#test:checked').length ? $('#test').val() : $('input[name=test]').eq(1).val();
```

Or written a different way

```
var value = $('input[name=test]').eq(!$('#test:checked').length).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me when selecting by name is:

```
$('[input[name="test"]')[0].checked
```

but selecting by id, as per your example:

```
$('#test').checked
```

should work also.

My first example was tested in FF and IE